# How to add jar to sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to build a sbt custom task where I want use "org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCrypt".

How can I make

```
"org.springframework.security" % "spring-security-crypto" % "5.1.2.RELEASE"
```

available in the sbt classpath so that I can import "org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCrypt" in "build.sbt"?

Comment: libraryDependencies will add the classes to project and won't available for build.sbt. To make 3rd party classes available to sbt I think you need to create custom sbt plugin

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks - make it an answer and I will mark it as correct

Comment: One more thing you can do is you can put your project on a git repo and can add that project as a dependency. To you main project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RajkumarNatarajan already mentioned, you can just create an **SBT** *plugin*, it is basically just another scala project that you then publish to a repository and latter uses it in your projects - this is useful if you need your task in many projects.

If you only need your task for one project, and do not want to create a *plugin*, you can add your dependencies in the `project/build.sbt` *file*, then create your *task* in the `project/Task.scala` *file*. This way you can use your *task* in your main `build.sbt` *file*, the dependency will be available to your task, but will not be added to your project and will be available to your task.